# Sum of 2 values in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 Tables like below

**Table - 1**

```
Bank_Name
Bank_ACNO
Bank_Branch
Bank_Balance
```

**Table - 2**

```
Emp_ID
Amount_Paid
```

Table-1 contains unique records for each Bank ACNO. But Table 2 contain Multiple records. Now i want to update Table - 1 (Bank_Balance) With Sum(Table-1.Bank_Balance + Amount_Paid)  where Table-1.Bank_ACNO=Table-2.Emp_ID.

I tried the below Query which did not Work.

```
UPDATE  Bank_Master
SET     Bank_Balance = ( Bank_Master.Bank_Balance
                     + Order_Archieve_Temp.Amount_Paid ) 
OUTER JOIN Order_Archieve_Temp 
ON Bank_Balance.Bank_ACNO=Order_Archieve_Temp.Emp_ID)
```

Comment: I don't see a query. Where's the select statement? Where's the from?

Comment: Do u want sum(A+B)? I mean sum of sum?

Comment: I hope that's not the actual query:  without a `WHERE` clause or an `INNER JOIN` it will update every row in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Here is the SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/099ae/1)**

**Below is the Update Query which you can try :**

```
Update T1
set T1.Bank_Balance = t1.Bank_Balance + t2.Amount_Paid
FROM TABLE1 T1,
     (select Emp_ID,sum(Amount_Paid) as Amount_Paid
        from Table2 
       group by Emp_ID ) as T2
WHERE T1.Bank_ACNO = T2.Emp_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
BEGIN TRAN;

UPDATE  t1
SET Bank_Balance = t1.Bank_Balance + ISNULL(x.Total_Amount_Paid,0)
-- or 
-- SET  Bank_Balance = ISNULL(t1.Bank_Balance,0) + ISNULL(x.Total_Amount_Paid,0)
-- or 
-- SET  Bank_Balance = NULLIF(ISNULL(t1.Bank_Balance,0) + ISNULL(x.Total_Amount_Paid,0), 0)
FROM    dbo.Table1 t1
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT  SUM(t2.Amount_Paid) AS Total_Amount_Paid
    FROM    dbo.Table2 t2
    WHERE   t1.Bank_ACNO = t2.Emp_ID    
) x

ROLLBACK
-- COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's going to remain your table design, you better keep your database under really tight control:  in most such circumstances, applications that have to determine a balance will do so by calculating it on-the-fly from some known and well-controlled state (say, from the last statement date) as a sum of *that* balance, and all the transactions that have occurred after then.

The current design appears vulnerable to miscalculation of the balance, and continued persistence of that error into the future.

Are there any possible concurrency issues here (could multiple parties possibly be executing this same statement from different connections?).   What is your transaction  isolation level?